# Understanding nftables logs

Tags: linux, debian, logs, nftables

What happened during these logs entry events below?

```
Nov* 8 09:37:12  kernel: [10967.520783] New Input packets: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=85 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=6855 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=1 [SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=57 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60616 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=49662 DPT=53 LEN=37 ]

Nov* 8 09:38:13 kernel: [11029.272652] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

1.In first example why squre brackets is used?

2. Numbers in squre brackets have the different meaning, why.
3. What is the meaning of 08:00 in the end of MAC address?
4. In second example what is the role of multicast address and 0.0.0.0 address.
5. Why TTL=1

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Nov* 8 09:37:12  kernel: [10967.520783] New Input packets: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.2 LEN=85 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=6855 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=1 [SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=57 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60616 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=49662 DPT=53 LEN=37 ]
```

`[10967.520783]` is the kernel uptime in seconds when the message was created. Originally this was the first part of the kernel log message. But the message seems to have been processed by something else (maybe a syslog daemon?) that has prefixed it with a human-readable timestamp and `kernel:` indicating that this message was logged by the OS kernel, not by any application or service.

The packet described by this log message came to Netfilter through the loopback interface (`IN=lo`), so there is no real Ethernet layer involved, and so source and destination MAC addresses are all zeroes. The `08:00` at the end of the `MAC=` string is probably the [EtherType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType), indicating that the "payload" of the low-level packet contains an IPv4 packet.

The source and destination IP addresses are both 192.168.1.2, so this packet seems to have been generated locally on host 192.168.1.2. Within the payload of the IPv4 packet, there is an [ICMP packet of Type 3, Code 1](https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml#icmp-parameters-codes-3) - that is, a "Host unreachable" error packet.

An error message is meaningless if you cannot figure out what caused it to be sent, so an ICMP error packet contains the headers of the original packet which caused the error to be detected. These headers are decoded within the square brackets:

```
 [SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=57 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60616 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=49662 DPT=53 LEN=37 ]
```

So, the packet that caused the `Host unreachable` error message was originated in this host (192.168.1.2) and its destination was 192.168.1.1. The protocol was UDP and the destination UDP port was 53, the standard DNS port. So, this host apparently has some configuration (either manually or by DHCP) that tells it to use 192.168.1.1 as a DNS server. But as it was trying to send an UDP packet to the DNS server at 192.168.1.1, something went wrong. The kernel may have detected that the network connection was lost, or the kernel tried to make an ARP request to find the MAC address of 192.168.1.1 but got no response. And so the kernel generated the ICMP error packet and sent it locally through the loopback interface.

---

```
Nov* 8 09:38:13 kernel: [11029.272652] New Input packets: IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8:5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

The timestamps and `kernel:` are explained the same as in the first message.

The packet described by this message came in through the `wlo1` wireless network interface. Assuming that the `MAC=` string is just the first 14 bytes from the beginning of the Layer-2 Ethernet packet, the destination MAC address (= presumably the MAC address of this host) would be `b8:81:98:cb:ef:a8`. According to one [MAC address lookup website](https://macvendors.com/), this MAC would belong to a network adapter (or other device) manufactured by Intel.

The source MAC address would be `5c:77:77:6e:0d:7b`. The vendor lookup failed to tell anything about this address.

Both MAC addresses are regular, globally unique unicast MAC addresses. That may be surprising as the packet contains a multicast IP address. This might be caused by how multicast messages are handled in Wi-Fi networks.

The `08:00` is again Ethertype, indicating plain old IPv4.

The destination IP address 224.0.0.1 is the standard "all-hosts" multicast address. Because it would not make sense to send packets to all multicast-capable systems in the whole internet, the `TTL=1` restricts this multicast to all hosts within a single subnet only.

`PROTO=2` indicates this is an [Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) packet: these are used by multicast routers and multicast-capable systems to find out which multicast groups each multicast-capable systems wants to be part of. (Every multicast-capable host is always part of the all-hosts group.) The IGMP data is not decoded in this message, but because the IP packet length is just 32 octets (`LEN=32`), this is most likely a IGMPv2 general membership query packet.

Basically, a multicast-capable router is asking for all multicast-capable systems to report if they want to receive any multicast traffic.

Comment: telcoM, thank you very much for detailed answer! It helped me a lot to understand my problem.

Comment: I didn't notice for the first time  and for that reason didn't ask: why in squre brackets two "LEN":  LEN=57 and LEN=37?

Comment: 57-37=20, which is exactly the size of the IPv4 header when there are no IP protocol options used (= the normal case). So LEN=57 would probably be the size of the IPv4 packet, and LEN=37 would be the size of the UDP packet (DNS query) inside it.